# How to get multiple inputs on the same line without white space

Tags: java, input, jgrasp, isbn

I am doing a program for my CS class. It wasn't hard to setup and it does what it is supposed to. My problem though is that I want it to take all the inputs on the same line without any white space. The program is supposed to take the first 9 digits of an ISBN and find the tenth and print it. I know you can do this by taking the numbers as a string and then parsing it (I believe?) so you can get the separate ints. Although I am not entirely sure I set up the while loop properly last time I tried and doing so would make me have to change my code entirely no? Here is the problem:
(Business: check ISBN-10) An ISBN-10 (International Standard Book Number)
consists of 10 digits: d1d2d3d4d5d6d7d8d9d10. The last digit, d10, is a checksum,
which is calculated from the other nine digits using the following formula:
(d1 * 1 + d2 * 2 + d3 * 3 + d4 * 4 + d5 * 5 +
d6 * 6 + d7 * 7 + d8 * 8 + d9 * 9) % 11
If the checksum is 10, the last digit is denoted as X according to the ISBN-10
convention. Write a program that prompts the user to enter the first 9 digits and
displays the 10-digit ISBN (including leading zeros). Your program should read
the input as an integer.
Either way here is the code without the loop taking in the inputs with the white space:

```
/* Class:        CS1301
* Section:       9:30
* Term:          Fall 2015
* Name:          Matthew Woolridge
* Instructor:    Mr. Robert Thorsen
* Assignment:    4
* Program:       1
* ProgramName:   ISBN_Number
* Purpose:       Prompts the user to enter the first nine numbers of an ISBN and calculates the tenth
* Operation:     The information to be numbers are statically instantiated in the code and
*                the table is output to the screen.
* Input(s):      The user inputs the first nine ISBN numbers
* Output(s):     The output will be the full the tenth ISBN number in the full number
* Methodology:   The program will use if statements and defined variables which use the user input variables to calculate the ISBN
* and return it to the user.
*
*/

import java.util.Scanner;
public class ISBN_Number
{

   public static void main (String[] args)
   {

     /******************************************************************************
      *                          Declarations Section                               *
      ******************************************************************************/
      /****************************CONSTANTS********************************/
      int [] ISBN = new int [8];
      int num1 = 0;
      int nextNum;
      int i; 
      int input=0;
      int num10=0;
      String fullIsbn;

      Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in); //Scanner utility initialization

     /******************************************************************************
      *                             Inputs Section                                  *
      ******************************************************************************/

      System.out.print("Please input the first nine digits (between 0-9) of your ISBN not including the leading 0: ");
      for (i = 0; i<ISBN.length;i++)
      {
         nextNum = scan.nextInt(); // For loop that asks for an input until it fills the array of 8
         ISBN[i] = nextNum;
         ++input;
      }

     /****************************variables********************************/
      if (input == 8)
      {
       num10 = (ISBN[0] * 1 + ISBN[1] * 2 + ISBN[2] * 3 + ISBN[3] * 4 + ISBN[4] * 5 + ISBN[5] * 6 + ISBN[6] * 7 + ISBN[7] * 8 + ISBN[8] * 9) % 11; // Calculates the value of num10
      }
      else 
      {
       System.out.println("You did not input enough or input too many digits.");
      }

     /******************************************************************************
      *                             Processing Section                            *
      ******************************************************************************/

      if (num10 == 10)
      { 
         fullIsbn = num1 + ISBN[0] + "" + ISBN[1] + "" + ISBN[2] + "" + ISBN[3] + "" + ISBN[4] + "" + ISBN[5] + "" + ISBN[6] + "" + ISBN[7] + "" + ISBN[8] + "" + "X";
      }
      else  // Determines if num10 is equal to x or not and prints
      {
         fullIsbn = num1 + "" + ISBN[0] + "" + ISBN[1] + "" + ISBN[2] + "" + ISBN[3] + "" + ISBN[4] + "" + ISBN[5] + "" + ISBN[6] + "" + ISBN[7] + "" + ISBN[8] + "" + num10;
      }

      /******************************************************************************
       *                              Outputs Section                                *
       ******************************************************************************/

      System.out.print("The full ISBN number is " + fullIsbn); // Prints the full 10 digit isbn
   } // Rnds string
} // Ends program
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the idea:

1. Take the user input as an index of an array of ints.
2. Sytem.out.print(yourArrayName[9]); //print out the 10th number of the array

For example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int [] ISBN = new int [10];
        int input =0;

        System.out.print("Give me 10 numbers: ");

        for (int i = 0; i<ISBN.length;i++){
            int nextNumber = keyboard.nextInt();
            ISBN[i] = nextNumber;
            ++input;

            if (input==10){
                System.out.print("The tenth number you gave me is: "+ISBN[9]);
            }
        }

    } 
}
```

You should be able to apply the above strategy like so to achieve what you are asking:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int [] ISBN = new int [10];
        int input =0;
        String fullIsbn;

        System.out.print("Give me 10 numbers: ");

        for (int i = 0; i<ISBN.length;i++){
            int nextNumber = keyboard.nextInt();
            ISBN[i] = nextNumber;
            ++input;

            if (input==10){
                ISBN[0]=0;
                ISBN[9] = (ISBN[0] * 1 + ISBN[1] * 2 + ISBN[2] * 3 + ISBN[3] * 4 + ISBN[4] * 5 + ISBN[5] * 6 + ISBN[6] * 7 + ISBN[7] * 8 + ISBN[8] * 9) % 11;
                if (ISBN[9] == 10)
                {

                    fullIsbn = ISBN[0] + "" + ISBN[1] + "" + ISBN[2] + "" + ISBN[3] + "" + ISBN[4] + "" + ISBN[5] + "" + ISBN[6] + "" + ISBN[7] + "" + ISBN[8] + "" + "X";
                }
                else  // Determines if num10 is equal to x or not and prints
                {
                    fullIsbn = ISBN[0] + "" + ISBN[1] + "" + ISBN[2] + "" + ISBN[3] + "" + ISBN[4] + "" + ISBN[5] + "" + ISBN[6] + "" + ISBN[7] + "" + ISBN[8] + "" + ISBN[9];

                }
                System.out.print("The tenth number you gave me is: "+fullIsbn);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I think I get what you were doing, I was trying that before but I need to calculate the tenth number with a formula that is given. If the tenth digit equals ten then it needs to print X. As shown from variables onward. The loop works though, thanks. ^^

Comment: Added a solution that could solve what you are asking. @snipem1438

Comment: Edit: It doesn't take all the inputs on one line without having to space, and once it does it returns an error. I will update to reflect what it currently looks like @JonathanScialpi

Comment: The answer I provided doesn't return an error for me. But at this point I think I wrote 90% of the program for you and this should be sufficient enough to get you to where you need to go since this is a hw problem.  @snupem1438

Comment: Okay, I should clarify that my problem is that I want these numbers to be entered on the same line without white space EX: 1234567. Right now it is still on separate lines or with entering. Otherwise it is fine. My last version of this code worked just as well but I was trying to use the array to remove white space. The help you have given thus far has been of great use though, thank you.